# How to get activation code to enable " code with me" option?

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

I want to  enable the option "code with me" for which I need to paste or drop an activation code. But I don't know what is that exactly and from where can I get that ??

I tried to start my coding journey and I found that to start that I need to enable the code withe option for which I needed an activation code . I expected to get that code via an email or something but it didn't happen.

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/code-with-me/buy/#personal.